# Struts 2 issue in Post request

Tags: struts2

I have form in which there are various fields.I have cross checked all fields by making my form as get type and cross checked all query string parameters .

Now let say there are 10 parameters in query string and in action while doing manipulation  i am only using 5 or 6 fields and remaining 4 fields are not coming in query string.

Now the problem is if i want to trace where my code break so if i put log or SOP at the start of action it does not show even SOP.

Just wanted to clear if some parameter which are not coming in query and are not in use i think my code should not break.or how to trace where the code is breaking

I even debug my code bt even that is not working

```
###################parameters in Query String ###########################

changeReadingFlag=false
&__multiselect_GroupSelect=
&outletId=15
&monthYear=2016-10
&dates%5B0%5D=01%2F10%2F2016
&newMeterReading%5B1%5D=01-Oct-2016
&dates%5B0%5D=01%2F10%2F2016
&newMeterReading%5B1%5D=
&outlettransactionmeterList%5B0%5D.runId=23
&outlettransactionmeterList%5B0%5D.meterReading=500.0
&outlettransactionmeterList%5B0%5D.calculatedMeterUnits=500.0
&hiddenFlag=true
&meterArrayList%5B1%5D.outletTransactionMeterBeanList%5B0%5D.change=Add+New+Week+Reading
&meterArrayList%5B1%5D.outletTransactionMeterBeanList%5B0%5D.weekno=0
&meterArrayList%5B1%5D.outletTransactionMeterBeanList%5B0%5D.customerId=30
&meterArrayList%5B1%5D.outletTransactionMeterBeanList%5B0%5D.newMeterId=17
&meterArrayList%5B1%5D.outletTransactionMeterBeanList%5B0%5D.outlettransactionmeterList%5B0%5D.meterReading=1200
&meterArrayList%5B1%5D.outletTransactionMeterBeanList%5B0%5D.newMeterId=17
&meterArrayList%5B1%5D.outletTransactionMeterBeanList%5B0%5D.customerId=30
&meterArrayList%5B1%5D.outletTransactionMeterBeanList%5B0%5D.outlettransactionmeterList%5B0%5D.isClosedAccount=false
```

In my action inside method, I am using only those parameters for which value is coming in query string. I have not used `validate()` method inside action.

Now if I print at start of this function will I get logs or not. Actually I am not getting log.

Comment: Do you see an exception?

Comment: @Roman there is no exception as of now. initially there was exception where it asked for result type input as i did not mentioned it earlier bt now no Logs are getting printed. I have added input type in result type .

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: <action name="savemeterTransactionReadings" class="com.ar.pack.actions.OutletTransactionAction"
   method="savemeterTransactionReadings"></action>

Comment: Nothing wrong with this code.

Comment: inside action tag resut type=success ,input and error all defined in this sequence

Comment: public String savemeterTransactionReadings() { system.ou.println("hii");   return SUCCESS;}

Comment: ok, post all relevant code

Comment: i will bt just general question if some parameters that are coming in Query string does not have value .will flow go to inside this savemeterTransactionReadings()  or directly reverted to input tag

Comment: it depends on if the value is required and validation has errors then it won't go, otherwise depends on the next  error.

Comment: @Roman thanks for your  help let me try at my end